# How to remove alpha channel in image using Jimp js?

Tags: javascript, jimp

I tried to use the code below or `.rgba(false)` which corrupted the file.

```
Jimp.read(img).then((image) => {
image.background(0x00000000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same issue, seems like this corrupting issue is already known ([see this opened GitHub issue](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/issues/681)).

One year late someone may have found how to solve it ([see this comment](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/issues/681#issuecomment-567918405)).

*Please note that I'm not an expert about editing node modules so don't blame me if this is an horrible way to achieve this, I only want to share something I found and that worked for me.*

As this comment suggested, I modified in Jimp's png module the index.js file (`node_modules/@jimp/png/dist/index.js`) the property `inputHasAlpha: data._rgba` to `inputHasAlpha: data.bitmap.alpha` and I was able to get a png file without alpha channel as intended.

Hopes this help!